# Do all +ssRNA viruses have similar structures and life cycles?

Tags: virus, virology

Take HCV for example. HCV doesn't package any enzymes in it's virions. When it infects a cell, it first translates its RNA genome. It's RdRp is synthesized with other non-structural proteins. Then its RdRp began replicating the RNA genome. Newly synthesized RNA are served as either translation templates or genomes of new virions. Finally new virions are assembled and released.

So do all +ssRNA viruses have the same pattern? There's no enzyme in the virions, and all the enzymes are synthesized after entry into the cells. They have the same life cycles: entry→translation(non-structural)→replication→translation(structural)→assembly→release.